# Tauri.js - Click through the window

Tags: javascript, tauri

To explain simply what I would like to do, I would like to create a window that would behave like an overlay, and that would let me click through it without interrupting the click (while superimposing itself on the other elements) (this is not very clear, so here is an example)

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD0HO.png)

The red border is the limit of the tauri window, I would like to be able to click for example on my code and continue to write without the focus being taken by the tauri window

I already tried to use `setIgnoreCursorEvents` from https://tauri.app/fr/v1/api/js/window/ but I think it has nothing to do / And it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is this an issue of html/JavaScript? Doesn't feel like a tauri issue

Comment: Try with css on main body of the frontend.
{
    pointer-events: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

There apparently isn't any solution directly provided by Tauri.
However, it seems doable with some custom OS code, more information is available in [a github issue](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/issues/184).